# FROM SQL SERVER QUERY INTO PANDASQL DATEDIFF RETURN IN MINUTE

Tags: python, sql, pandasql

Hay Everyone
I am trying to translate my SQL server query into pandasql

so the task is to get the average time (in minutes) between 2 process

this is my query on the SQL server

```
select payment_method,cast(avg(cast(cast(DATEDIFF(second,booking_created_time,booking_paid_time) as float)/60 as float)) as decimal(20,2)) as difference_minute  
from fact_flight_sales
group by payment_method
```

the query returns the in decimal form
so the code gonna return every avg below 1 min in decimal

this is my code on pandasql

```
q2 = """
select payment_method,booking_created_time,booking_paid_time,(booking_created_time-booking_paid_time)
from dffact_flight_sales
group by payment_method

"""
print(sqldf(q2, locals()))
```

pandas SQL only returns the day difference, not the hour and minute.
how can I make the query? work exactly like my SQL server query?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd



dffact_flight_sales = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\lixfe\Desktop\fact_flight_sales.csv")



dffact_flight_sales['time difference'] = ((pd.to_datetime(dffact_flight_sales['booking_paid_time']) - 
                            pd.to_datetime(dffact_flight_sales['booking_created_time']))
                                .dt.total_seconds() / 60)

GK = dffact_flight_sales.groupby('payment_method')


GK1 = GK[['payment_method','time difference']]
GK1.first()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).